# django rest-auth social connect to Vkontakte (vk)

Tags: django, django-allauth, vk, django-rest-auth

Please help me make **REST** social **connect** for provider **Vkontakte**.
I'm using **django-allauth** library (https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth). 
And **django-rest-auth** for REST auth (https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth).

I've **already have VKOAuth2Serializer that works fine for login** and register.
But connect doesnt' work.
Here is urls:

```
url(r'^rest-auth/vk/connect/$', views.VkConnect.as_view(), name='vk_connect'),
url(r'^rest-auth/vk/', views.VkLogin.as_view()),
```

Views:

```
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.oauth2.client import OAuth2Client
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.vk.views import VKOAuth2Adapter

class VkLogin(CustomSocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = VKOAuth2Adapter
    serializer_class = VKOAuth2Serializer
    client_class = OAuth2Client
    callback_url = 'http://localhost:3000'

class VkConnect(SocialConnectView): 
    adapter_class = VKOAuth2Adapter
    #May be here should be something else?
```

Serializer:

```
from allauth.socialaccount.helpers import complete_social_login
from rest_auth.registration.serializers import SocialLoginSerializer
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
from rest_framework import serializers

class VKOAuth2Serializer(SocialLoginSerializer):
    email = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    user_id = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        view = self.context.get('view')
        request = self._get_request()

        if not view:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_("View is not defined, pass it as a context variable"))

        adapter_class = getattr(view, 'adapter_class', None)
        if not adapter_class:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_("Define adapter_class in view"))

        adapter = adapter_class(request)
        app = adapter.get_provider().get_app(request)

        # Case 1: We received the access_token
        if attrs.get('access_token'):
            if not attrs.get('user_id') or not attrs.get('email'):
                raise serializers.ValidationError(_("Incorrect input. email and user_id is required with access_token."))

            access_data = {
                'access_token': attrs.get('access_token'),
                'user_id': attrs.get('user_id'),
                'email': attrs.get('email'),
            }

        # Case 2: We received the authorization code
        elif attrs.get('code'):
            self.callback_url = getattr(view, 'callback_url', None)
            self.client_class = getattr(view, 'client_class', None)

            if not self.callback_url:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(_("Define callback_url in view"))
            if not self.client_class:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(_("Define client_class in view"))

            code = attrs.get('code')

            provider = adapter.get_provider()
            scope = provider.get_scope(request)
            client = self.client_class(
                request,
                app.client_id,
                app.secret,
                adapter.access_token_method,
                adapter.access_token_url,
                self.callback_url,
                scope
            )
            access_data = client.get_access_token(code)
            if attrs.get('email'):
                access_data['email'] = attrs.get('email')
            if not access_data.get('email'):
                raise serializers.ValidationError(_("Incorrect input. Social account must have email, otherwise send it in email field."))
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_("Incorrect input. access_token or code is required."))

        social_token = adapter.parse_token({'access_token': access_data['access_token']})
        social_token.app = app

        try:
            login = self.get_social_login(adapter, app, social_token, access_data)
            complete_social_login(request, login)
        except HTTPError:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_('Incorrect value'))

        if not login.is_existing:
            login.lookup()
            login.save(request, connect=True)
        attrs['user'] = login.account.user

        return attrs
```

And here is view for registration/login and urls that works fine:

**Please help me make REST connect for Vkontakte.**

the project is here:
https://github.com/taime/imetrics

**When trying to connect VK - I get error:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/vk/connect/

Django Version: 2.0.3
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django_filters',
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
'rest_auth',
'django.contrib.sites',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'rest_auth.registration',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.vk',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
'storages',
'core',
'api']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/tema/Sites/instametrics/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/tema/Sites/instametrics/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/tema/Sites/instametrics/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/tema/Sites/instametrics/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/tema/Sites/instametrics/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/tema/Sites/instametrics/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/tema/Sites/instametrics/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/tema/Sites/instametrics/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/Users/tema/Sites/instametrics/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_auth/views.py" in dispatch
49.         return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/tema/Sites/instametrics/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
494.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/Users/tema/Sites/instametrics/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
454.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/Users/tema/Sites/instametrics/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
491.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/tema/Sites/instametrics/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_auth/views.py" in post
93.         self.serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

File "/Users/tema/Sites/instametrics/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in is_valid
236.                 self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)

File "/Users/tema/Sites/instametrics/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in run_validation
438.             value = self.validate(value)

File "/Users/tema/Sites/instametrics/code/core/serializers.py" in validate
73.             login = self.get_social_login(adapter, app, social_token, access_data)

File "/Users/tema/Sites/instametrics/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_auth/registration/serializers.py" in get_social_login
58.         social_login = adapter.complete_login(request, app, token, response=response)

File "/Users/tema/Sites/instametrics/code/allauth/socialaccount/providers/vk/views.py" in complete_login
54.         extra_data = resp.json()['response'][0]

Exception Type: KeyError at /rest-auth/vk/connect/
Exception Value: 'response'
```

Comment: Could you please post an error that you got from connect view?

Comment: KeyError at /rest-auth/vk/connect/
'response'
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://instametrics.gyds.ru/rest-auth/vk/connect/
Django Version: 2.0.3
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 
'response'
Exception Location: /code/allauth/socialaccount/providers/vk/views.py in complete_login, line 54

Comment: I've checked this. When I'm trying to connect VK, it creates new account instead of connecting it to current...

Comment: Do you use same email for both accounts?

Comment: I use different emails... but it's works ok with connecting twitter and facebook (it has different emails too). Only VK creates new account instead of connecting. Is it possible make vk works the same way, the twitter and facebook does?

Comment: If you use different email, how does it know that it is you..? I am not sure since this logic is on the VK side, the only difference with connect is, it attaches social account to you regular account, but Login logic is the same.

Comment: It knows my current account, because I'm sending authorization token in header in my POST request to connect. That's how it knows that it's me.  And it works with twitter and facebook. You can try it yourself if don't believe me:
Register: https://instametrics.gyds.ru/accounts/login/
Connect with browser: https://instametrics.gyds.ru/accounts/social/connections/
Connect with REST: rest-auth/twitter/connect/

Comment: I believe you, I am just not sure about the solution, since this logic would be part of VK adapter..

Comment: It looks like this logic has been already included to twitter connecter... So may be it's possible to use twitter solution for vk ?

Comment: `app.secret` always returns `''` for me? any help please?

Answer (score 2):

Since VK requires custom provider logic, you need to use serializer with logic defined in `VKOAuth2Serializer` but with social login state process being set to `connect`. You can achieve it by creating a subclass of `VKOAuth2Serializer` with `SocialConnectMixin`.

So your new serializer and connect view would look the following way:

Serializer:

```
from rest_auth.registration.serializers import SocialConnectMixin


class VKOAuth2ConnectSerializer(SocialConnectMixin, VKOAuth2Serializer):
    pass
```

View:

```
class VkConnect(SocialConnectView): 
    adapter_class = VKOAuth2Adapter
    serializer_class = VKOAuth2ConnectSerializer
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check it and comeback later

Answer (score 0):

VK API version field is required now. You can rewrite VKOAuth2Adapter class from github repo 
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/providers/vk/views.py

Comment: Thanks, I know, I already have vk api version field. As I said REST Login works fine. I need REST connect to be working fine too. 
Normal connects (not REST) also works fine for vk. 
Now need to make it work by REST...